# calculate the net value in every time hour depending on two columns in r

Tags: r

I have question related to calculation based on timestamp:
I have a big dataframe `df`with `Timestamp` (whole year), `Export_Country`,  `Import_Country` and respective `Value` in each hour of the year.
For example here is the sample dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(Timestamp=c("2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000"),
                     Export_Country=c('AT','DE','CH','DE','CZ','DE'), 
                     Import_Country=c('DE','AT','DE','CH','DE','CZ'), 
                     Value=c(170.06,289.37,1133.47,0,68.29,0.32),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to write a function which can calculate the net value in each timestamp within two countries. The output should look like the dataframe `df1`:

```
df2<- data.frame(Timestamp=c("2F020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000","2020-01-01 00:00:00.000"),
                 Export_Country=c('DE','CH','CZ'), 
                 Import_Country=c('AT','DE','DE'), 
                 Value=c(119.31,1133.47,67.97),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I was trying to do something like:

```
df3<- df %<>% 
     group_by(Timestamp,Export_Country,Import_Country) %>% 
     summarise(Value=sum(Value))
```

Note this is output of `str(mydataframe)`

```
'data.frame':   65520 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ DateTime      : chr  "2020-01-02 12:00:00.000" "2020-01-02 12:00:00.000" "2020-01-02 12:00:00.000" "2020-01-02 12:00:00.000" ...
 $ Export_Country: Factor w/ 70 levels "AL","AT","BA",..: 15 13 15 10 13 2 53 13 46 10 ...
 $ Import_Country: Factor w/ 70 levels "AL","AT","BA",..: 10 46 13 15 2 13 10 15 13 53 ...
 $ FlowValue     : num  417 251 898 0 1089 ...
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Can we please see your attempt and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: Hi@Sotos to be honest I don't know what to do. But I was trying something like `df3<- df %<>% 
     group_by(Timestamp,Export_Country,Import_Country) %>% 
     summarise(Value=sum(Value)) `

Comment: Since countries can export and import to and from one another, why those choices of export and import in `df2`?

Comment: @Rui Barradas It's just an example, I want only net value while keeping import and export country columns in `df2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that the following function is complicated and that problably there are simpler solutions but it seems to work.

```
fun <- function(X){
  f <- function(x){
    x[[3]]*(2*(x[[1]] < x[[2]]) - 1)
  }
  icontr <- grep("Country", names(X), value = TRUE)
  X[["Value"]] <- f(X[c(icontr, "Value")])
  X[icontr] <- t(apply(X[icontr], 1, sort))
  fmla <- paste(c("Timestamp", icontr), collapse = "+")
  fmla <- paste("Value", fmla, sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  out <- aggregate(fmla, X, sum)
  i <- out[["Value"]] < 0
  tmp <- out[["Export_Country"]][i]
  out[["Export_Country"]][i] <- out[["Import_Country"]][i]
  out[["Import_Country"]][i] <- tmp
  out[["Value"]][i] <- -out[["Value"]][i]
  out
}


fun(df)
#                Timestamp Export_Country Import_Country   Value
#1 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000             DE             AT  119.31
#2 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000             CH             DE 1133.47
#3 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000             CZ             DE   67.97

all.equal(fun(df), df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @mitco I cannot tell. The error is thrown in what instruction? Can you post a data example that gives the error?

Comment: Sorry my mistake this is an error `Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate` this is an error message with `In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(x[[1]], x[[2]]) :`

Comment: @mitco No rows to aggregate? What are the dimensions of the data set? As for the warning, can you post the output of `str(df)` in the question'

Comment: Rui Barradas Thanks a lot I noticed that datatype in sample data frame and original data frame was not consistent. Now it works super!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` we can pivot the data to longer format and

```r
# gets the next other country's index based on the current country index
funcp <- function(x) x + 1 - 2 * (x%%2 == 0)

df %>% 
  # pivoting to longer format in order to facilitate data manipulation
  pivot_longer(cols=ends_with("Country"), values_to = "country") %>% 
  # remove _Country from (Import|Export)_Country and getting the real value of the transaction Imports = - Value
  mutate(name=sub("_.+","", name), Value=Value*(1-2*(name=="Import")))  %>% 
  # adding a with column that contains the counterpart
  tibble(with=.$country[funcp(1:nrow(.))]) %>% 
  # finally grouping by the Timestamp, the country and the counterpart to get the actual Net value
  group_by(Timestamp, country, with) %>% summarise(Value=sum(Value)) -> df2

df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Timestamp, country [4]
#>   Timestamp               country with    Value
#>   <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 AT      DE     -119. 
#> 2 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CH      DE     1133. 
#> 3 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CZ      DE       68.0
#> 4 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 DE      AT      119. 
#> 5 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 DE      CH    -1133. 
#> 6 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 DE      CZ      -68.0
```

If you want to get only the positive nets then you can filter the results :

```r
df2 %>% filter(Value >=0)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   Timestamp, country [3]
#>   Timestamp               country with   Value
#>   <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CH      DE    1133. 
#> 2 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CZ      DE      68.0
#> 3 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 DE      AT     119.
```

Note : czech to germany Value is rounded in the printing process but is equal to 67.97 in the tibble

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might want to combine `Import_Country` and `Export_Country` into a single character string? Then you can `group_by` this, and take difference between the two `Value`s present. This assumes you only have two countries to combine for each `Timestamp`. It also subtracts import from export consistently.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(CountryDyad = paste(pmin(Export_Country, Import_Country),
                             pmax(Export_Country, Import_Country), 
                             sep = "-")) %>%
  group_by(Timestamp, CountryDyad) %>%
  summarise(Value = Value[which(startsWith(CountryDyad, Import_Country))] -
                    Value[which(startsWith(CountryDyad, Export_Country))])
```

**Output**

```
  Timestamp               CountryDyad   Value
  <chr>                   <chr>         <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 AT-DE         119. 
2 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CH-DE       -1133. 
3 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 CZ-DE         -68.0
```